# What's the proper way to pass an array to a WMI Method?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, wmi

I'm writing a function in C# that queries WMI, uses the objects returned from WMI as parameters to a method in a different WMI class.

```
private void InstallUpdates()
{
    ManagementScope sc = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\ccm\clientsdk");
    ManagementClass c = new ManagementClass(@"CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager");
    ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM CCM_SOFTWAREUPDATE WHERE COMPLIANCESTATE=0 AND EVALUATIONSTATE < 2");
    c.Scope = s.Scope = sc;

    ManagementObjectCollection col = s.Get();
    List<ManagementObject> lUpdates = new List<ManagementObject>();

    //Install each update individually and track progress
    int index = 1;
    foreach (ManagementObject o in col)
    {


        object[] args = { o };

        object[] methodArgs = { args, null };

        lblCurrentAction.Text = "Now running method: Install Updates " + o.Properties["Name"].Value + " EvalState=" + (UInt32)o.Properties["EvaluationState"].Value;

        c.InvokeMethod("InstallUpdates",methodArgs);

        lblCurrentUpdate.Text = "Now Installing Update " + index + " of " + col.Count + ": " + o.Properties["name"].Value;

        UInt32 intProgress = (UInt32)o.Properties["PercentComplete"].Value;

        UInt32 evalState = (UInt32)o.Properties["EvaluationState"].Value;

        lblCurrentAction.Text = lblCurrentAction.Text + " EvalState: " + evalState;

        while (evalState <=  7)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = (intProgress <= 100) ? (int)intProgress : 100;
            evalState = (UInt32)o.Properties["EvaluationState"].Value;
            intProgress = (UInt32)o.Properties["PercentComplete"].Value;
            lblCurrentAction.Text = lblCurrentAction.Text + " EvalState: " + evalState;
        }

        ++index;

    }





}
```

I pasted the entire function for reference, but the problem lines are #1,2, and 4 inside the foreach loop. From the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155394.aspx) the method takes as a parameter an array of ccm_softwareupdate objects, which I've successfully queried from a different class (and am running a foreach on the collection), so I know that the objects exist.

Any, as these are system updates, I'd like to install them one at a time, at least during testing, but when I pass a single object array to the method

```
object[] args = { o };

c.InvokeMethod("InstallUpdates", args);
```

I get a cast error:

> unable to cast object of type 'system.management.managementobject' to system.array

So somewhere it's obviously seeing my array as only one object. I know it's not making it to the WMI method because I don't see the update starting to install.

From reading on the internet, I've also tried what's in the function now:

```
object[] args = { o };

object[] methodArgs = { args, null };

c.InvokeMethod("InstallUpdates", methodArgs);
```

The key here was to create a *second* array that holds the first array and a null value as the second value. This actually works and the WMI method is invoked, but it never *returns* from the method, the code just hangs. Switching the arguments around

```
object[] methodArgs = { null, args };
```

Reveals that it actually hangs on the null argument, because here the update never starts installing. I've also tried this as a sanity check

```
object[] args = { o, o };

c.InvokeMethod("InstallUpdates", args);
```

But I get the same casting error, so I must be on the right track with the double array method. Also, using

```
object[] methodArgs = { args, 0};
```

or

```
object[] methodArgs = { args };
```

Doesn't work.

To reiterate, I'm looking for a way to pass an array to a WMI Method using C#.

---

**Update**

This powershell script does the same thing, and actually works. The only difference is that it's initial array has more than one object, but that shouldn't matter.

```
    #    '=================================================================== 
#    ' DISCLAIMER: 
#    '------------------------------------------------------------------- 
#    ' 
#    ' This sample is provided as is and is not meant for use on a  
#    ' production environment. It is provided only for illustrative  
#    ' purposes. The end user must test and modify the sample to suit  
#    ' their target environment. 
#    '  
#    ' Microsoft can make no representation concerning the content of  
#    ' this sample. Microsoft is providing this information only as a  
#    ' convenience to you. This is to inform you that Microsoft has not  
#    ' tested the sample and therefore cannot make any representations  
#    ' regarding the quality, safety, or suitability of any code or  
#    ' information found here. 
#    '  
#    '=================================================================== 

# This is a simpple get of all instances of CCM_SoftwareUpdate from root\CCM\ClientSDK 
$MissingUpdates = Get-WmiObject -Class CCM_SoftwareUpdate -Filter ComplianceState=0 -Namespace root\CCM\ClientSDK 

# The following is done to do 2 things: Get the missing updates (ComplianceState=0)  
# and take the PowerShell object and turn it into an array of WMI objects 
$MissingUpdatesReformatted = @($MissingUpdates | ForEach-Object {if($_.ComplianceState -eq 0){[WMI]$_.__PATH}}) 

# The following is the invoke of the CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager.InstallUpdates with our found updates 
# NOTE: the command in the ArgumentList is intentional, as it flattens the Object into a System.Array for us 
# The WMI method requires it in this format. 
$InstallReturn = Invoke-WmiMethod -Class CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager -Name InstallUpdates -ArgumentList (,$MissingUpdatesReformatted) -Namespace root\ccm\clientsdk
```

Comment: Do you know anything about the `InstallUpdates` method itself?  It seems clear that the casting error you refer to is the result of that method wanting to receive an array for some reason.  If the call to `InvokeMethod` never returns, then I presume an exception is being consumed at some level.  Have you any idea what that might be?

Comment: You're correct, you need the extra array since p1 is an array.  I'm thinking null is the instance object here and should come first, you could try c.CreateInstance() instead of null.  (but the hang may be due to something else as well, like the scope)

Comment: @ebyrob putting `c.CreateInstance()` first gave me a cast error again, putting it second gave me the same hang. I have posted a powershell script that actually works, I just don't know how to do the same in c#.

Comment: @MDMoore313 what was the cast exception?  It should tell you what the expected first parameter is...

Comment: It looks like your InstallUpdates Method is expecting a CCM_SoftwareUpdate Data Type,  Your object array contains a ManagementObject Type, I am not sure how it would be done perhaps you need to cast to CCM_SoftwareUpdate then fill your array and pass it along.  You powershell script is doing that as well its passing array of CCM_SoftwareUpdate.

Comment: @ebyrob System.Array of course...

Comment: @Bearcat9425 you're correct, but since that is a WMI Class (See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155451.aspx)), how would I pass this type to the method? The method must at least recognize the ManagementObject type somewhat, as the method executes and the update installs, but the method never returns, even after the update is finished installing.

Comment: Well if the update is installing and just not returning then you are right it must accept that ManagementObject Type.  I am not sure how you would cast it if its even possible to cast perhaps ManagementObject is the expected type. I dont do a whole lot with WMI and practically nothing with CCM I was just looking at the InstallUpdate Method and it said it expected the CCM_SoftwareUpdate Data Type but perhaps it can extract that type from ManagementObject. see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155394.aspx.  You might need to assign a var to that method call and check that value.

Comment: You might try catching SMS error types as well, not sure if you already are or just catch generic exceptions.  See here for the SMS exception types you can catch that might give some more detail.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh949216.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this question while looking for a C# way to trigger the CCM Agent to install an update. Here's what I have running in a production app.

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\CCM\ClientSDK", strComputerName), string.Format("SELECT * FROM CCM_SoftwareUpdate WHERE Name=\"{0}\"", strUpdateName)))
foreach (var obj in searcher.Get())
    using (var mInv = new ManagementClass(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\CCM\ClientSDK", strComputerName), "CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager", null))
        mInv.InvokeMethod("InstallUpdates", new object[] { new ManagementBaseObject[] { obj } });
```

Comment: Nested array looks right, although I am no longer in the SCCM business I am very much still in the C# business. Enjoy some rep for your efforts.